# Fast way of detecting directory changes

Tags: php, file, file-io

Currently I'm comparing modification dates with some data stored in the DB, but it's still slow because I'm forced to do it for all files (scan entire dir structure):

```
DIR1
  file1
  file2
  DIR2
    file3
    file4    
    ...
```

Is there any other way to detect if for example file3 was modified, so I can update DB?

Can I make the operating system automatically update the modification date of the root dir, when a file or inner dir has been modified (edited/renamed/added/deleted)? This way I will only need to check the modification date of the root dir (DIR1).